# Using transition in a styled component with @emotion/core

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I am trying to implement a short transition to when a button is clicked.
The mechanism that sets the `isOpen` property works fine.
My problem is that it won't animate, but only flip the content at once.
The expectation was that it should create an extra class but it just renders the component with a different class.

I tried:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
    transition: transform 0.25s linear;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen && css`transform: rotate(180deg)` }
  `;
```

And also:

```
    transform: ${({ isOpen }) => isOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : 'rotate(0de)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Does the isOpen variable correspond to the clicked state or you want to rotate with different values based on the isOpen variable when the button is clicked?

Comment: @subashMahapatra The isOpen is toggled when the button is clicked

Comment: Have you tried using the :active pseudo selector for the `transform: rotate(180deg)` with and keeping `transform: rotate(0deg)` for the base style. :active pseudo selector should trigger the rotation when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but i imported the wrong package.

I used

```
import { css } from '@emotion/css'
```

instead of

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react'
```